# In implementation files, should we prefer "using namespace" directives or wrapping the implementation in namespace { }?

Tags: c++

I often see in cpp files code that is written as

```
namespace foo
{
    ... // implementation of class methods etc, belonging to the namespace foo
} // namespace foo
```

Where the implementation is wrapped by the namespace so that the namespace prefix isn't needed such as, foo::some_class::method().

I also often see

```
using namespace foo;

... // implementation of class methods etc, belonging to the namespace foo
```

The former, seems to imply you're putting the code in that namespace, which isn't really what is happening. The latter seems cleaner to me and more direct. Is this purely stylistic or is there a reason not to use the second form?

Comment: They do two completely different things -- the second just imports namespace foo for name lookup.  All the names declared after that are still defined relative to the global scope.

Comment: `using namespace xxx;` should be avoided.

Comment: @ChrisDodd To clarify, the class declaration in the header will be wrapped in a namespace. Both forms in the implementation will assist in name lookup. Wrapping the class method definitions in the namespace will not actually bring the class into the namespace, correct?

Comment: wrapping makes everything in the wrapped block inside the namespace.  If you try to define some method for a class that is not in the namespace in the wrapped block, you'll get an error.

Comment: I guess that was what I was thinking. It doesn't compile because it doesn't pull it into the namespace. One advantage is I see that it requires you to define and declare in the same namespace.  A using directive is much looser as it would work if your class was declared in global or in the namespace added by using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prefer warpping. For class member functions, there is little difference, for when you write:

```
void clazz::foo() {
  // ...
}
```

then `clazz` will be looked of by regular unqualified lookup, which will find the class name you introduced with the using directive.

However, for *free functions*, the difference is vast, this here

```
void foo() {
  // ...
}
```

will introduce a *new function*, declared and defined in the global namespace. And it will be unrelated to the function declared in the namespace.

The only way to gain consistency (without fully qualifying your definitions by the namespace), is to wrap the definitions in the reopened namespace.